# Solve this math problem in smallest amount of code

Tags: code-golf, math

[Here](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/496/aside-from-brute-force-how-can-i-solve-this-puzzle/1906#1906) I found a cool math problem. I thought you could write some golfed code to compute all answers between x and x.(there is an infinite amount).

Problem:
Once upon a time, and old lady went to sell her vast quantity of eggs at the local market. When asked how many she had, she replied:

Son, I can't count past 100 but I know that:

- If you divide the number of eggs by 2 OR 3 OR 4 OR 5 OR 6 OR 7 OR 8 OR 9 OR 10, there will be one egg left.
- If you divide the number of eggs by 11 there will be NO EGGS left!

How many eggs did the old lady have?

i answered the question on that thread with:

```java
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++)
        {
            boolean a = true;
            for (int x = 2; x < 11; x++)
            {
                if (i % x != 1) a = false;
            }
            if (i % 11 != 0) a = false;
            if (a) System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
```

Catch: 
If some sharp eyed person noticed, you could start at 25201 and keep adding 27720  to get to the next one. You can NOT use this machanic to answer the question.
So dont post something like this:

```
public class test {
public static void main(String... args) {   
    long l=25201;
    while(true){
        System.out.println(l);
        l+=27720;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: It's not clear (a) what output you expect: the two programs in the question give different output; (b) where the line is between permitted and forbidden application of basic number theory.

Comment: The first thing you do when you spot a math related challenge is doing math (number theory). If you can't use the best method (number theory) it's not challenging anymore.

Comment: "compute all answers between x and x"?

Comment: See the comment on [this standard loophole entry](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/1063/2104). Code golf challenges where the output is constant are uninteresting without a Kolmogorov Complexity twist, which would be uninteresting in this question anyway.

Answer (score 1):

## R, 37 chars

```
n=121;while(!all(n%%2:10==1))n=n+11;n
```

**Edit**: if the question was: "Found all possible answers between x and y" then it's **65** characters as a function:

```
f=function(x,y)(x:y)[!rowSums(outer(x:y,2:10,`%%`)!=1)&!x:y%%11]
```

Example:

```
> f(1,1e5)
[1] 25201 52921 80641
```